# loop statement to display latest post in the latest news box

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written this code to loop through the last 6 posts and display their titles in latest news box below the header. The post appear fine but they cannot be clicked to go to the post.
Heres the code

```
<div id="freshlyWrapper">
<div id="freshlyposts">
<?php
$freshlyIonised = new WP_Query();
$freshlyIonised->query('category_name=featured&showposts=6');
while($freshlyIonised->have_posts()):
$freshlyIonised->the_post();
?>

<div class="freshlyionisedbox"><h3><?php the_title(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `a` inner:

```
<a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
  <?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
```

Now your titles are outside those correspondent links

Comment: Great. But the problem is that now they appear blue and are underlined. I want that text to be black and not underlined

Comment: `<a style='text-decoration: none; color: blue;'` You better learn some [`CSS`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) ;-)

Comment: Yes. I don't think the OP can create stylesheets and use them, that's why I proposed to learn `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to set the title WITHIN the a tag:

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

And add a semicolon after the permalink function:

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```